# ngOnChanges won't log form changes

Tags: angular

I'm learning `ngOnChanges` from the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#using-change-detection-hooks). It's not logging changes in the HTML form.

I imported `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` into `app.module.ts`:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I made a little form in `app.component.html`:

```html
Favorite Color: <input type="text" [formControl]="favoriteColorControl">

<p>Your favorite color is {{favoriteColorControl.value}}.</p>
```

In `app.component.ts` I imported `Input`, `OnChanges`, `SimpleChanges` and the forms module. Then I made an `@Input` object and set up `ngOnChanges` to log changes:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() favoriteColorControl = new FormControl('');

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(this.favoriteColorControl.value);
    console.log(changes);
    console.log(changes.favoriteColorControl.currentValue);
  }
}
```

The form works. If you type "pink" into the form, it tells you that your favorite color in pink. But nothing logs in the console.

I read somewhere that `ngOnChanges` only detects changes passed from a child component to a parent component. I made a child component and displayed the child view in the parent view but that didn't log anything.

Comment: You are doing it so wrong. Reactive forms does not use `@Input` therefore it is not subject to ngOnChanges.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it so wrong. Reactive forms does not use `@Input` therefore it is not subject to `ngOnChanges`. You claim that you "follow" tutorial, but there is not such thing in it. Using @Input is one thing, using reactive forms is very different thing.

`ngOnChanges` will fire when some of (current) component @Input bindings will change. In your case you are not binding anything (from outside of component like `<app-component [favoriteColorControl]="something">`) so it wont work.

To listen to changes of reactive control, use `favoriteColorControl.valueChanges.subscribe(ctrlValue=>doSomethingWithIt)`